# Why can't gases produce second harmonic generation (ie, why is $\chi^{(2)}$ always zero)?

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

To quote wikipedia on [second-harmonic generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation):

> Since media with inversion symmetry are forbidden from generating
> second-harmonic light via the leading-order electric dipole
> contribution (unlike third harmonic generation), surfaces and
> interfaces make interesting subjects for study with SHG.

I've never understood why a gas cannot produce second harmonic generation (through a true $\chi^{(2)}$
nonlinearity). What do they mean by "inversion symmetry" and why does this make $\chi^{(2)} = 0$.

Also an intuitive argument here would be appreciated. (That is, what is it about gases that stop them from turning a pair of frequencies into a single photon, when it can turn 3 waves into a 4th wave? )

Comment: In the Wiki article, "inversion symmetry" is hyperlinked to [point reflection/inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection). Can you be more specific what about that is unclear to you?

Comment: Is your question about an intuitive argument why gases have inversion symmetry, or why something with inversion symmetry does not produce dipole SHG?

Comment: @sleepy, an intuitive argument for why this symmetry would forbid $\chi^{2}$ is what I'm looking for. I think I loosely understand why a gas would be have some type of spatial symmetry, so that definition is probably not the source of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I guess the link you provided is pretty clear. As I said to sleepy, I suspect that this isn't the main issue of my misunderstanding. Although technically, I don't see exactly why this symmetry is guaranteed for gases (is this the same thing as arguing that the wavefunction producing the dipole is spherically symmetric? if it is, then don't superpositions of different spherically symmetric states stop this from being true?)

Comment: The way this is usually taught is that you write $P_i(2\omega)=\chi^{(2)}_{ijk}E_{j}(\omega)E_k(\omega)$ and then invert all the axes (i,j,k). Mathematically, everything changes their signs, but due to inversion symmetry P stays the same. So comparing the two equations, one concludes on $\chi^{(2)}_{ijk}=-\chi^{(2)}_{ijk}$, or $\chi^{(2)}_{ijk}=0$. This way it is seen that this holds true for all even-order susceptibilities ($\chi^{(2)}$, $\chi^{(4)}$ etc), but not odd-order. Not sure how intuitive this is though.

Comment: What I'm about to comment is just my educated guess: first you need a gas where the molecules lack inversion symmetry (you should be able to find those I guess). However, this means that when interacting with the laser, for them to produce any $\chi^2$ process, they would have to be oriented a certain way. This means that the chance of creating a second order photon is already small as your interaction cross section is hyper small. Then you have complications due to phase-matching, hence, chi2 processes, for free motion gases, is neglegible, but I do not think impossible.

Comment: but here is a paper showing SHG in gases: [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/25/11/025/meta?casa_token=p9F9L3lBPqIAAAAA:8bzxXQxtPOLjaFMJWaRG1tvLghP2rvEbpQa-KTGG_yWb0t4Dc7qYWOgbE2WdxWHzy-DXuHRlm6M) 
However, the symmetry is broken with the plasma
I would like to say that after some thought, the chance that a molecule in free motion gas is aligned for SHG has another molecule, with same probability, to do it in anti-phase, so there are always pairs of photons in phase, anti-phase and there is never a build-up of signal. Hence the symmetry in gases breaks shg

Comment: @JoséAndrade, interesting point there. I don't completely understand it but I think I'm starting to get the picture.